How to get id from sequence without nextval() in postgres?
I'm trying to figure out how to insert new data into a database while explicitly setting the ID. However, when I use nextval('user_seq'), it doesn't retrieve the next value from the sequence as expected; instead, it increments it based on the value I inserted earlier:
demo at db<>fiddle
CREATE TABLE users
(
    user_id        BIGINT NOT NULL,
    user_firstname VARCHAR(50),
    user_lastname  VARCHAR(50),
    user_nickname  VARCHAR(100),
    user_email     VARCHAR(255),
    user_password  VARCHAR(255),
    user_role      VARCHAR(20),
    CONSTRAINT pk_users PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS user_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 50;

INSERT INTO users VALUES 
 (nextval('user_seq'), 'First Name', 'First Lastname', 'First Nickname', 'first@email.gg', 'First pass', 'USER_PRESENTER')
,(nextval('user_seq'), 'Second Name', 'Second Lastname', 'Second Nickname', 'second@email.gg', 'Second pass', 'USER_ELECTOR')
RETURNING *;




user_id
user_firstname
user_lastname
user_nickname
user_email
user_password
user_role




1
First Name
First Lastname
First Nickname
first@email.gg
First pass
USER_PRESENTER


51
Second Name
Second Lastname
Second Nickname
second@email.gg
Second pass
USER_ELECTOR




I expected that nextval() will get next id from sequence, but nextval increment it by 'default' value.

I thought about currval() but this method should be in context of query.


I also tried pg_get_serial_sequence()  but I had error that I can't use it in this query.
Maybe I did something wrong, I never used it before.

Please share the DDL for the table and sequence involved. On the other hand, why would you like to try to do it like this? An ID is just an identifier without any meaning, so who cares what the number is?

@FrankHeikens I am writing test on java with testcontainers and i want be sure that my sequence is work.
When using the SEQUENCE strategy with the allocationSize parameter, Hibernate pre-allocates a block of identifiers that will be used for generating object IDs. For example, with allocationSize = 50, Hibernate retrieves a range of values from the database (e.g., 1–50) and will use these for objects without querying the database each time for a new ID value.
This reduces the number of database calls, improving performance when creating objects in bulk.

Answering "How to get id from sequence without nextval() in postgres?" - you can select*from user_seq; and the first field will be currval that you can combine with info in pg_sequences.increment_by
As to pg_get_serial_sequence() not working - it won't work unless the sequence is owned by the column and in your case they aren't linked in any way.

Sequence pre-fetching is pretty common and you don't need the increment by 50 for it to work. It'll just act like it ran 20x nextval() and grab 1, 51, 101, 151 and so on. I still don't see why you'd do that and how that helps pre-fetching. Maybe you actually wanted to modify the sequence cache setting? Also, consider ditching varchar for text and using identity columns instead of serial and manually handled sequences.

Use an identity column to prevent Hibernate from messing with your database. If you care about performance, you'd better eliminate Hibernate.

If you wanted to jump ahead for some reason, you can leave the default increment by 1 and setval(currval('user_seq')+50) whenever you need the jump. Not sure what that'd help with. The pre-allocated elements are reflected in the sequence which guarantees no two calls to nextval() get the same element, ever, so it's not like this caching behaviour risks collisions. You do get gaps resulting from pre-allocated then unused and discarded elements and you get out-of-order values because even if workers fetch nextval in order, they don't necessarily commit their inserts in order.

You need to read this Create sequence, in particular what the difference is between INCREMENT BY and CACHE(which I suspect is what you want). Just know sequences are not guaranteed to be gapless nor provide numbers in order between sessions.

The nextval() function behaves as it should, given how you defined the sequence - What Does the nextval() Function Do in PostgreSQL
If you want to increment by 1, define the sequence accordingly:
CREATE SEQUENCE user_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

Perhaps you meant to use the CACHE parameter instead of INCREMENT BY.
CREATE SEQUENCE user_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 50;

More details about creating sequence and the parameters.

That is working just as it should. If you define a sequence with START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 50, then the calls to nextval() for that sequence will return the values 1, 51, 101, 151, etc. If that is not what you want, you have to define the sequence differently.
A sequence is a counter: the first call to nextval() returns the starting value, and on every subsequent call, the counter is incremented by the INCREMENT (default 1).
Perhaps you should define the sequence with CACHE 50 instead of INCREMENT BY 50. Then each call to nextval() will add one to the previous result, as you seem to desire. The effect of CACHE 50 is that the first call to nextval() actually reserves 50 values from the sequence, and the following 49 calls to nextval() will use these cached values. The benefit is that the database backend does not have to access the sequence on every nextval() call, which improves the performance if there are many calls to nextval().

Ok now i get it INCREMENT BY different in Hibernate and SQL query. What I want is to fetch blocks of 50 IDs in a single query and store them in memory (Java/Hibernate) for later use. The reason is that during testing, we drop and repopulate a temporary database before each test. So, each time I insert a new user, it results in an additional database query, which increases the overall execution time.
So maybe for test i should use ALTER SEQUENCE user_seq INCREMENT BY 1 RESTART WITH 1;

I see. ThenINCREMENT [BY] 50 is actually the correct solution. But then you shouldn't call the database function nextval() to get the next number from the batch of 50 you retrieved, you have to keep track of the numbers in the application. I don't know if Hibernate has any support for that so that you don't have to code it yourself. If you insert the rows like you show in your example, I recommend that you don't do any such caching of sequence values in the application, but you define the sequence with CACHE 50 like I suggested in my answer. As I described, there won't be any overhead.
